# How can i create a mongo user using ruby mongo client without password being exposed?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I need a mongo client with user of only read access for all databases.
Also i need the ruby mongo client to be created without the password hardcoded?

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

just use standard ruby mongo driver: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver

here you have API documentation in which you'll find details on authentication (essentially it requires passing `user` and `password` keys in initialization data): http://api.mongodb.com/ruby/2.5.0/Mongo/Client.html

--

> Also i need the ruby mongo client to be created without the password
>   hardcoded

You can always keep authentication details in your app's config

OR

for example pass it in environment variables when starting process [they will be available through `ENV` hash]. Example of how it is used
`RAILS_ENV=developent rails s` - `RAILS_ENV` is an environment variable accessible in your app by `ENV['RAILS_ENV']`
If you decide to do it this way you can keep authentication outside your app on the machine on which you're running your app.